# Logic Gates - Dmux (nand2tetris)

Tags: boolean-logic, mux, nand2tetris

I'm just started to take the nand2tetris course ! In the first project, it's demanded to build logic gates with "Nand" starting with "Not". Well, it was easy at the beginning, building or, and, xor. **But then came "Multiplexor". It took me a while deciding which gates to use...** Then I discovered a new technique called "Canonical Representation" and the problem are easily solved.

**But here comes the issue** : De-multiplexor !!! It has two outputs, so I'm stuck, how to implement this two output gate using Canonical Representation ?

---

*^ above is solved ^*

---

And I have a more general problem. **How do you people build these gates !** **Is it possible to logically come with an implementation of a Multiplexor gate** for instance ?

Comment: Haha ! Update, after thinkering a bit on a paper, It just came to my mind ! **But the second question still exists !**

Comment: any reference on `Canonical Representation`? and how do you easily solve mux?

Comment: "Canonical Representation" in Elements of Computing Systems refers to "sum of products" in boolean algebra: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/sum-of-product.html For DMux, write two such sum-of-product expressions, one for each output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have built the basic logic gates (And, Or, Xor...) then a demultiplexor can be built out of three of these components.

Consider the state description you are given:

`/**
 * Demultiplexor:
 * {a, b} = {in, 0} if sel == 0
 *          {0, in} if sel == 1
 */`

Simply build two circuits, one that computes a, and one that computes b. You can connect your inputs (in and sel) to both circuits.